# Drawing slice in cocos2d-js

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I wrote a game with [Phaser](http://phaser.io) engine but sadly i didn't get any good performance even with cocoonjs. I tried to optimize it but i don't think i can optimize enough.

So i'm trying to switch to cocos2d-js. I tried some examples with cocos2d and it works well. I think i will get the performance i'm looking for. I just need to achieve two things. I tried to use methods in DrawNode class but i couldn't do it. I'm new to computer graphics.

- Drawing a slice, Just like the drawSlice method from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ElliotChong/6060346)
- Writing text along an arc with the given radius and angle

Update: I'll need the expensive calculations done by native code. I have around 18 of this shape independently animating the radius by 75-200 pixels in 100ms with user input. The problem i faced in Phaser was this expensive calculations.

Update2: Right now i'm able to draw [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFc4A.png) with @Sebastian's help. It's still incomplete.

Update3: I got good performance with Phaser with a few hacks. Maybe i won't need this, though others might need it.

Slice:
[image: Slice]

Text:
[image: curve text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that functionality isn't done yet in cocos2d-html5. The best solution I can offer you is this function [I submitted a while ago](http://cocos2d-x.org/issues/3129#note-1). It's not ideal, but it should do the trick. I'll wrap this function in the neccesary boilerplate code later if you don't know what to do with it (I'm a few hours away from my home PC and I don't have the time to make a full example right now):

```
var drawSolidArc= function(center, radius, degreesFrom, degreesTo, segments){
    if(degreesTo<degreesFrom){
        var temp = degreesTo;
        degreesTo = degreesFrom;
        degreesFrom = temp;
    }
    var i;
    for(i=degreesFrom; i<=degreesTo;i++){
        cc.drawingUtil.drawCircle(center, radius, cc.DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-i+90), segments, true);
    }
};
```

Also, this code is for v2.2.2, and it should be migrated to use v2.2.3's (or v3) `DrawNode`. Sorry for the incomplete answer, but I hope it'll send you in the right direction for the moment.

As for writing curved text, I think this is the closest thing I know exists: https://github.com/supersuraccoon/CircleLabelTTFDemo-HTML5

Comment: Thanks for reply, i'll try your solution in a few hours.

Comment: I could only draw [this](http://i.imgur.com/FqnqpCp.png) with your function. I can workaround something to draw the slice. I would like to know most effective way to tween that drawing. I will change degreesFrom and degreesTo and the shape will redrawn with those new variables. I can draw instantly after changing but i don't think it will give me any good performance. Can you give me some examples on dynamic custom drawing objects.

Comment: I think i got this, i extended Node class and created a member DrawNode object. In my Node's draw function i'm calling drawNode.draw(ctx).

Comment: I'm deeply sorry for the delay. Yes, what you need to do is create a draw function that redraws each frame (don't worry, it doesn't have as bad performance as it sounds).

Comment: Sorry, I sent that comment by mistake and it didn't let me edit afterwards. It continues:
The quickest guidance I can give you is to go to the `samples/tests/DrawPrimitivesTest/DrawPrimitivesTest.js` file and look at the `DrawOldAPITest` test. In there, add my function and call it within the `draw` method. I've used this code as a "prgress-circle" in this sample prototype: http://proto.heart-bit.com.ar/2013_08-joy_inc/ (look at the bottom right once in-game, it changes when you press the "arrow" button)